# else and if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, runtime

World!

I am currently self teaching my self C++. I am reading principals and practice using C++ and while writing a program for one of the exercises I got curious about an outcome from a program I wasn't expecting. If anybody could explain why this is that would be nice

Source code below:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double val1 = 0;
    double val2 = 0;

    cout << "Enter two floating point values: ";
    cin >> val1 >> val2;

    cout << val1 + val2 << '\n'
         << val1 * val2 << '\n'
         << val1 / val2 << '\n';

    if(val1 > val2)
    {
        cout << val1 << " greater \n";
        cout << val2 << " lesser \n";
    }

    if(val1 == val2)
    {
        cout << val1 << " equals other floating point value \n";
        cout << val2 << "equals other floating point value \n";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << val2 << " greater \n";
        cout << val1 << " lesser \n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

When I type in something like 6.9 and 5.4, it gives me this output:

6.9 greater
5.3 lesser

5.3 greater
6.9 lesser

I have fixed the issue by changing the else statement to an if statement, but could somebody tell me why it's giving be this output when I use the else statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your code should look like this:

```
if(val1 > val2)
{
    cout << val1 << " greater \n";
    cout << val2 << " lesser \n";
}

else if(val1 == val2)
{ //^^you missed this else

    cout << val1 << " equals other floating point value \n";
    cout << val2 << "equals other floating point value \n";
}

else
{
    cout << val2 << " greater \n";
    cout << val1 << " lesser \n";
}
```

The logic is very clear if you miss that `else`. Specifically, it will execute the first `if` block. then go the `else` block if you do not have that `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Below code:

```
if(val1 == val2) {
   cout << val1 << " equals other floating point value \n";
   cout << val2 << "equals other floating point value \n"; 
}

else {
   cout << val2 << " greater \n";
   cout << val1 << " lesser \n"; 
}
```

`6.9 != 5.4`, so it goes to `"else"` part and give you the second output

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` only attaches to the second `if` so your code goes into the `else` block unless `val1` and `val2` are equal.

To get the behaviour you want using `else` you have to use it before the second `if` as well:

```
if(val1 > val2)
{
    cout << val1 << " greater \n";
    cout << val2 << " lesser \n";
}

else if(val1 == val2)
{
    cout << val1 << " equals other floating point value \n";
    cout << val2 << "equals other floating point value \n";
}

else
{
    cout << val2 << " greater \n";
    cout << val1 << " lesser \n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! I get it now. I just had a brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

You have an else working for the second if so the val2>val1 condition would work everytime the == condition is false.
there can be many solutions to it.

Answer (score 0):

else statement is associated with nearest if statement. for example you have written

```
if(val1>val2)
{
  // do something
} 
if(val1==val2)
{
   // do something
} 
else
{
   // do something
}
```

here 'else' statement is associated with nearest if(val1==val2).  listen, say val1=10 & val2=9
now first if with 'val1>val2' condition will be tested. it is true(10>9 is true) then second if with condition 'val1==val2' will be tested it is false(10==9 is false),, now 'else' MEANS IS THE MOST NEAREST 'if' IS FALSE. IF ANSWER IS YES THE EXECUTES THE STATEMENTS UNDER 'else'. So Think as plain English. when you give your friend a condition with ELSE ,,, your friend must ask which was the condition associated with IF. So your fault is you wanted to treated 'else' as 'if(val1 < val2)' you can replace else with 'else if(val1 < val2)' & will find the expected output.